# Weird empty line under toolbar

Tags: eclipse

I got this weird empty line in Eclipse! It appeared just today! It's locate right under the toolbar. It's driving me mad!

It looks like this:
[image: Picture of weird empty line]

Observations:

- It's there in all perspectives.
- It's not there if I use another workspace.
- Hiding and showing toolbar doesn't help.
- Resetting perspective doesn't help.
- *Close all perspectives* does help! But then I can't do anything!
- Restarting with `-clean` doesn't help.
- Removing `workbench.xmi` doesn't help.
- Removing `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs` doesn't help.

How can I get rid of the weird empty line? Possibly by messing around with the workspace settings files?

Or do I have to start with a clean workspace? :( There is so much stuff there that I don't know how to transfer, such as application server and database connections.

I'm using Eclipse 4.4.0, the Java EE bundle, on Windows 8, 64 bit.

Comment: OMG!! It's happened again! In a totally unrelated workspace. This I have because of my sins. Please Internet, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victory!

I found that deleting a certain workspace configuration file makes the weird empty line magically disappear. The file is this one:

```
WORKSPACE_DIR/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.prefs
```

The file is re-generated on start up (or is it shut down?). I don't know what is stored in it and what is lost when I remove it but I didn't notice any loss of configuration information.

I also fount that **the appearance of the weird empty row is triggered by switching to the "Windows XP Olive" theme**. It doesn't go away by switching to another theme however.

I solved it by removing configuration file one by one until I found the right one.